# Transform a string into an array of bytes

Tags: c#

I found this little snippet to to transform a string into an array of bytes:

```
    public byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }
```

And this one to transform an array of bytes into a string:

```
    public string GetString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
        return new string(chars);
    }
```

But I notice that the first one returns an array twice as big as the initial string (because sizeof(char) = 2) and every other slot in my array is a 0.

Example:

```
string = TEST
bytes[] = { 84, 0, 69, 0, 83, 0, 84, 0 };
```

I'm using this function to send packets in UDP, so I need my packets to be the smallest possible.

Why is the array twice bigger? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET actually uses UTF-16 encoding to store `string`'s and `char`'s, which means each character is actually encoded with 2 bytes. This is detailed in [Character Encoding in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#encodings):

> UTF-16 encoding is used by the common language runtime to represent `Char` and `String` values, and it is used by the Windows operating system to represent `WCHAR` values.

So you should expect to get 2 bytes for every character in your string.

If you want to only get 1 byte for per character you have to use a different encoding. For this input, [ASCII encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx) will work:

```
public byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
}
```

Calling this with the input `"TEST"` will return `{ 84, 69, 83, 84 }`

Comment: @AK_ sure but you never know what OP's going to be using this for. If he/she really needs a 1-to-1 correspondence between chars and bytes, UTF-8 won't work either. I showed ASCII in my answer because I figured it's the encoding OP's most likely to be familiar with.

Comment: UTF8 is compatible with ASCII, that is charecters from 0x00 to 0x7F, would be represenred th same in both...

Answer (score 4):

To get bytes for a string use:

```
Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes()
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

To go back to string use:

```
Encoding.Utf8.GetString()
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

In C#, [char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx) is a 16-bit datatype because .NET uses Unicode UTF-16 encoding natively.

If your test is entirely ASCII data, then you can use [ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.getbytes.aspx) to convert your string to bytes using the ASCII encoding.

It's probably better to use [UTF8Encoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.getbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert to bytes using the UTF8 encoding. This supports the entire Unicode character set, not just ASCII, but encodes it in a way that doesn't include all of those zero bytes the way UTF16 does.

There's also [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) if you need to learn more about character encodings.